# Is Pentaho Reporting Output component of PDI works without parameters

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-report-designer

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B7lOc.jpg)
Below is my requirement with example.
1.Base report will have data from this query.
     Base report query:select * from Animals;
   I used above query in prpt for base report.
2.I want to generate 2 saperate reports from above data using same prpt as my report design.I dont    want to create again same prpt for 
Report_1_query and Report_2_query as mentioned below.
   Report_1_query: select * from Animals where AnimalType="Dog";
 
   Report_2_query: select * from Animals where AnimalType="Cat"; 
   This I was tried using Pentaho Reporting Output component with parametrs and its working    fine.But I dont want to use parameters.
3. Now if you see screenshot I have taken all data in Table Input Component and applied java filter     to select particular records and passed that records to 
Pentaho Reporting Output     component.According to me it will not work.If its not possible with this approach,request you to     suggest any other way to acheive this.

Transformation screenshot attached for the reference.Getting below error while running attached transformation.

```
2018/04/20 15:29:12 - Pentaho Reporting Output.0 - ERROR (version 8.0.0.0-28, build 8.0.0.0-28 from 2017-11-05 07.27.50 by buildguy) : Unexpected error
2018/04/20 15:29:12 - Pentaho Reporting Output.0 - ERROR (version 8.0.0.0-28, build 8.0.0.0-28 from 2017-11-05 07.27.50 by buildguy) : org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleException: 
2018/04/20 15:29:12 - Pentaho Reporting Output.0 - There was an unexpected error processing report '' to produce file 'B' with processor: PDF.
2018/04/20 15:29:12 - Pentaho Reporting Output.0 - Unable to parse the document: ResourceKey{schema=org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.resourceloader.loader.URLResourceLoader, identifier=file:/C:/Pentaho/design-tools/data-integration, factoryParameters={}, parent=null}
2018/04/20 15:29:12 - Pentaho Reporting Output.0 - 
2018/04/20 15:29:12 - Pentaho Reporting Output.0 -  at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.pentahoreporting.PentahoReportingOutput.processReport(PentahoReportingOutput.java:317)
2018/04/20 15:29:12 - Pentaho Reporting Output.0 -  at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.pentahoreporting.PentahoReportingOutput.processRow(PentahoReportingOutput.java:126)
2018/04/20 15:29:12 - Pentaho Reporting Output.0 -  at org.pentaho.di.trans.step.RunThread.run(RunThread.java:62)
2018/04/20 15:29:12 - Pentaho Reporting Output.0 -  at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
2018/04/20 15:29:12 - Pentaho Reporting Output.0 - Caused by: org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.resourceloader.ResourceCreationException: Unable to parse the document: ResourceKey{schema=org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.resourceloader.loader.URLResourceLoader, identifier=file:/C:/Pentaho/design-tools/data-integration, factoryParameters={}, parent=null}
2018/04/20 15:29:12 - Pentaho Reporting Output.0 -  at org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.xmlns.parser.AbstractXmlResourceFactory.create(AbstractXmlResourceFactory.java:214)
2018/04/20 15:29:12 - Pentaho Reporting Output.0 -  at org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.resourceloader.DefaultResourceManagerBackend.create(DefaultResourceManagerBackend.java:225)
2018/04/20 15:29:12 - Pentaho Reporting Output.0 -  at org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.resourceloader.ResourceManager.create(ResourceManager.java:382)
2018/04/20 15:29:12 - Pentaho Reporting Output.0 -  at org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.resourceloader.ResourceManager.create(ResourceManager.java:334)
2018/04/20 15:29:12 - Pentaho Reporting Output.0 -  at org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.resourceloader.ResourceManager.createDirectly(ResourceManager.java:200)
2018/04/20 15:29:12 - Pentaho Reporting Output.0 -  at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.pentahoreporting.PentahoReportingOutput.loadMasterReport(PentahoReportingOutput.java:164)
2018/04/20 15:29:12 - Pentaho Reporting Output.0 -  at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.pentahoreporting.PentahoReportingOutput.processReport(PentahoReportingOutput.java:176)
2018/04/20 15:29:12 - Pentaho Reporting Output.0 -  ... 3 more
2018/04/20 15:29:12 - Pentaho Reporting Output.0 - Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:/C:/Pentaho/design-tools/data-integration; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Content is not allowed in prolog.
2018/04/20 15:29:12 - Pentaho Reporting Output.0 -  at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
2018/04/20 15:29:12 - Pentaho Reporting Output.0 -  at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
2018/04/20 15:29:12 - Pentaho Reporting Output.0 -  at org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.xmlns.parser.AbstractXmlResourceFactory.create(AbstractXmlResourceFactory.java:205)
2018/04/20 15:29:12 - Pentaho Reporting Output.0 -  ... 9 more
2018/04/20 15:29:12 - Pentaho Reporting Output.0 - Finished processing (I=0, O=0, R=2, W=1, U=0, E=1)
2018/04/20 15:29:12 - TradeBlotterAnother - ERROR (version 8.0.0.0-28, build 8.0.0.0-28 from 2017-11-05 07.27.50 by buildguy) : Errors detected!
2018/04/20 15:29:12 - Spoon - The transformation has finished!!
2018/04/20 15:29:12 - TradeBlotterAnother - ERROR (version 8.0.0.0-28, build 8.0.0.0-28 from 2017-11-05 07.27.50 by buildguy) : Errors detected!
2018/04/20 15:29:12 - TradeBlotterAnother - ERROR (version 8.0.0.0-28, build 8.0.0.0-28 from 2017-11-05 07.27.50 by buildguy) : Errors detected!
2018/04/20 15:29:12 - TradeBlotterAnother [enter image description here][1]- Transformation detected one or more steps with errors.
2018/04/20 15:29:12 - TradeBlotterAnother - Transformation is killing the other steps!
```

Comment: By looking at the screen-shot it looks it is not proper, describe your requirement clearly.

Comment: @WorkingHard.. I edited the question with proper requirement.

Comment: If your type if fixed let’s say cat and dogs then you can use switch case condition and use two Pentaho reporting output steps. It will solve your issue of not keeping parameters and generate two reports.

Comment: @WorkingHard.. applying javafilter or switch case will not solve the problem.Report getting displayed based on query in prpt file.we need to think how can we modify that one from PDI to generate 2 different reports using PRO.